# Tune parameters from a specific equation in R

Tags: r, predictive-models, fitting, parameterization

This is the first time I am truing to tune model parameters in R. I have a fairly complicated equation with multiple parameters:

```
wage <- 6375
alfa <- 11.25
beta <- 0.39
phi <- 0.16
psi <- 0
def.labor <- 38/255
ag.cost <- 30
def.cost <- 100
net.carbon <- 418
ag.price <- 1.7*1000
pes <- 5
r <- 0.06

(((wage*beta^(1-(1/phi))*alfa^(-1/phi)*ag.price^(-1/phi)*(-r*def.cost+net.carbon*pes+ag.cost-r*psi*def.labor-r*psi+psi)^((1/phi)-1))/phi)^(phi/(beta+phi-1)))
```

The equation returns an estimated AREA. I would like to tune the parameters ALFA, BETA, and PHI to approximate the estimated area to a real observed area. I have looked into some model tuning packages available for R but as I understood they do not let me select the functional form of my equation, so I wonder if anyone is aware of a package that would allow me to do so? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "tune" and what do your data look like (if you have any)?

Comment: Sorry about that, maybe I am not using the right terms. The equation returns an optimum amount of land. The ALFA, BETA, and PHI parameters are from a production function.  The values I have assigned to them are simply initial/testing values. So basically, that equation returns 8.10 right now and I want to change those variables to make the equation returns 12.5 (the averaged observed amount of land).

Comment: In principle, you will obtain a two-dimensional set of solutions.  That implies you need to impose additional constraints.  Without them, it's unclear how your problem is related to subjects of interest on this site, such as statistics and machine learning.

Comment: @geekoverdose The OP is trying to find solution(s) to a nonlinear equation, not perform optimization.  Your discussion of NP hard and a host of somewhat dubious (in my opinion) "global" optimization methods, is rather off the mark.  Actually, finding solutions to the desired equation is quite easy in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve one nonlinear equation in 3 variables.  As @whuber pointed out in a comment to the question, there is a two-dimensional (infinity) of solutions to your problem.

Something along the lines of package nleqslv in R might do the trick (I've never tried it). You could also use a function for nonlinear least squares, by taking the square of the difference between left-hand side and 12.5 as the objective function.

I used other methods, which for purposes of this discussion are irrelevant, in order to provide 3 different solutions. For each solution, I fixed 2 of the variables at the original values and solved for the 3rd.  But there is a two-fold infinity of other solutions.

Solution 1: alfa = 13.6714, beta = 0.39, phi = 0.16

Solution 2: alfa = 11.25, beta = 0.4327, phi = 0.16

Solution 3: alfa = 11.25, beta = 0.39, phi = 0.2677

As whuber suggested, you can impose various constraints, or incorporate them into an objective function, if you wish to focus the solutions in a particular way.   You could even put a tolerance around 12.5 and not insist the equation be solved exactly.